# only one column width changes with table-layout fixed (html/CSS)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am programming in css and html. i made a table but when the page width changes only one column changes width it instead of every. For styling reasons I used different tags for different td-elements. the table. the relevant code is probably the css part with the `table-layout:fixed;` line.

```css
/* basic style*/

.c_container{
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;



}
.c_week{
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
.c_td:hover{
  background-color: #add8e6;
}
.c_November{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
}
.c_weekdays{
  color: black;
  background-color: #D0F0C0;
}
.c_calendar, .c_th, .c_td, .c_week{
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border:3px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  cursor: pointer;

}
.c_td{
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 10px;

}

/* markere helg */

.c_weekend{
  background-color: #FED8E1;
}
/* markerer datoer som ikke er i november */
.c_graydays{
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

/* markere spesielle hendelser*/

.c_expedition, .c_talent, .cr_talent{
  background-color: #FFFCBB;
}
/* hover*/
.c_expedition .c_expeditiontext {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.c_expedition:hover .c_expeditiontext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.c_talent .c_talenttext {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.c_talent:hover .c_talenttext {
  visibility: visible;
}
.cr_talent .cr_talenttext {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.cr_talent:hover .cr_talenttext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js" async></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="c_container">
      <div class="c_November" >
        <h2 id="c_title">November 2020</h2>

      </div>
      <table id="c_calendar" >
        <tr>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Week</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Mon</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Tue</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Wed</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Thu</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Fri</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Sat</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Sun</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td class="c_week " >44</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >26</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >27</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >28</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >29</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >30</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_weekend c_td"  >31</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>


          <td class="c_week " >45</td>
          <td class="c_td">2</td>
          <td class="c_td">3</td>
          <td class="c_td">4</td>
          <td class="c_td">5</td>
          <td class="c_td">6</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">7</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">8</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="c_week ">46</td>
          <td class="c_td">9</td>
          <td class="c_td">10</td>
          <td class="c_td">11</td>
          <td class="c_td">12</td>
          <td class="c_td">13</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">14</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">15</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="c_week" >47</td>
          <td class="c_td">16</td>
          <td class="c_td">17</td>
          <td class="c_td">18</td>
          <td class="c_expedition c_td">19
            <span class="c_expeditiontext"> Thursday the 19th of November all pupils will have an expedition to damlia, our local dam. There we will learn more about insects and other wildlife near the dam. The trip will be from 08:00 to 15:00. Meet at the main entrance 07.45 and remember to pack a lunch!</span>
          </td>
          <td class="c_td">20</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">21</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">22</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="c_week ">48</td>
          <td class="c_talent c_td">23
            <span class="c_talenttext">  23rd of november is the time for the biyearly talentshow! The show will take place in auditorium A1 at 18.00 til 21.00.</span>  </td>
          <td class="cr_talent c_td">24
            <span class="cr_talenttext"> This is a rerun of yesterdays talentshow, except this time parents are welcome as well! (at auditorium A1 18.00 - 21:00)</span>

          </td>
          <td class="c_td">25</td>
          <td class="c_td">26</td>
          <td class="c_td">27</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td" >28</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="c_week ">49</td>
          <td class="c_td">30</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >1</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >2</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >3</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td"  >4</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_weekend c_td"  >5</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_weekend c_td" >6</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

This is text to post my question
This is text to post my question
This is text to post my question
This is text to post my question
This is text to post my question
This is text to post my questionThis is text to post my question
This is text to post my question
This is text to post my question
This is text to post my question
This is text to post my question
This is text to post my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `width: 100%` *only* to the table itself (`#c_calendar` ), not to the cells or other elements (i.e. erase it from the  rule for `.c_calendar, .c_th, .c_td, .c_week`).

If you want the first column to be wider than the others, you can apply a `min-width` setting to it.

Edit: If you want all other cells to always have the same width, you can apply a `min-width` to `.c_td`, which I just added in my snippet below.

To force *all* cells to have the same width (if possible, depending on content), you can also simply apply `min-width` to `td` (and maybe also `th`).

```css
/* basic style*/

.c_container{
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;



}
.c_week{
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
.c_td {
  min-width: 50px;
}
.c_td:hover{
  background-color: #add8e6;
}
.c_November{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
}
.c_weekdays{
  color: black;
  background-color: #D0F0C0;
}
#c_calendar {
  width: 100%;
 }
.c_calendar, .c_th, .c_td, .c_week{
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border:3px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  cursor: pointer;

}
.c_td{
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 10px;

}

/* markere helg */

.c_weekend{
  background-color: #FED8E1;
}
/* markerer datoer som ikke er i november */
.c_graydays{
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

/* markere spesielle hendelser*/

.c_expedition, .c_talent, .cr_talent{
  background-color: #FFFCBB;
}
/* hover*/
.c_expedition .c_expeditiontext {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.c_expedition:hover .c_expeditiontext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.c_talent .c_talenttext {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.c_talent:hover .c_talenttext {
  visibility: visible;
}
.cr_talent .cr_talenttext {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.cr_talent:hover .cr_talenttext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js" async></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="c_container">
      <div class="c_November" >
        <h2 id="c_title">November 2020</h2>

      </div>
      <table id="c_calendar" >
        <tr>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Week</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Mon</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Tue</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Wed</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Thu</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Fri</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Sat</th>
          <th class="c_weekdays c_th">Sun</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td class="c_week " >44</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >26</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >27</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >28</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >29</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >30</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_weekend c_td"  >31</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>


          <td class="c_week " >45</td>
          <td class="c_td">2</td>
          <td class="c_td">3</td>
          <td class="c_td">4</td>
          <td class="c_td">5</td>
          <td class="c_td">6</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">7</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">8</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="c_week ">46</td>
          <td class="c_td">9</td>
          <td class="c_td">10</td>
          <td class="c_td">11</td>
          <td class="c_td">12</td>
          <td class="c_td">13</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">14</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">15</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="c_week" >47</td>
          <td class="c_td">16</td>
          <td class="c_td">17</td>
          <td class="c_td">18</td>
          <td class="c_expedition c_td">19
            <span class="c_expeditiontext"> Thursday the 19th of November all pupils will have an expedition to damlia, our local dam. There we will learn more about insects and other wildlife near the dam. The trip will be from 08:00 to 15:00. Meet at the main entrance 07.45 and remember to pack a lunch!</span>
          </td>
          <td class="c_td">20</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">21</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">22</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="c_week ">48</td>
          <td class="c_talent c_td">23
            <span class="c_talenttext">  23rd of november is the time for the biyearly talentshow! The show will take place in auditorium A1 at 18.00 til 21.00.</span>  </td>
          <td class="cr_talent c_td">24
            <span class="cr_talenttext"> This is a rerun of yesterdays talentshow, except this time parents are welcome as well! (at auditorium A1 18.00 - 21:00)</span>

          </td>
          <td class="c_td">25</td>
          <td class="c_td">26</td>
          <td class="c_td">27</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td" >28</td>
          <td class="c_weekend c_td">29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="c_week ">49</td>
          <td class="c_td">30</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >1</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >2</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td" >3</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_td"  >4</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_weekend c_td"  >5</td>
          <td class="c_graydays c_weekend c_td" >6</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot:) do you have any advice on how every cell will stay the same width and height?